# Multi type object in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

from an API call i get as response a body with this structure

```
open class BaseResponseEntity {

    @SerializedName("result")
    val result: ResultEnum = ResultEnum.NONE

    @SerializedName("errorCode")
    val errorCode: String = ""

    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    val errorMessage: String = ""

    @SerializedName("successMessage")
    val successMessage: String = ""

    @SerializedName("value") 
    val code: LastPaymentCodeModel?

}
```

where the field "value" can be three types: null, String or LastPaymentCodeModel. How can i get this?
I managed to put a ? so that both null and LastPaymentCodeModel are handled, but i don't know how to handle the String type too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would probably be to use type `Any?` for `code`.
Then you should write a custom GSon serializer/deserilizer (`JsonDeserializer<BaseResponseEntity>`) for the `BaseResponseEntity` object.

In this Json deserializer, you would need to check the type of `value` (e.g is it a string or a data structure) and decode it to the correct object type.

Alternative, to avoid the use of `Any?`, you could leave the model exactly as you have it. You will still need to write a custom `JsonDeserializer`, however if `value` is a string then it would still create a `LastPaymentCodeModel`, using the string value as one of it's properties.